# Can't make an SSH connection to Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, ssh, connection

So I tried to make an ssh connection with my raspberrypi (running raspbian ) over ethernet. This used to work but somehow it doesn't anymore. I think the issue is that my raspberry pi can't get an ipadress, but how do I fix this? I have tried to clear the cache and all but with no success. Anyone ideas?

Comment: The raspi fetches the IP address from a DHCP server, if you configured the raspi to use dhcp. I see two possibilities why this doesn't work anymore. 1st your reconfigured the raspi not to use DHCP, or 2nd your DHCP server (Internet-Router, or whatever) is down  or does not accept the raspis MAC asdress for any reason.

Comment: What IP address does your Pi have and what IP address does the computer you're connecting from have? Can they `ping` each other?

Answer (score 1):

Because you guess that the RasPi may not get an ip address I assume that you are using a DHCP server on your network. Depending on the network environment it may be possible the pool of ip addresses, reserved to give to devices, is used up. Check your DHCP server and if required increase the pool for reserved ip addresses.